# Please explain the Quotient Rule

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, quotient-spaces

I am currently working on an equation but I'm having a hard time understanding how to get the answer.

the answer is ${(x^2-4)(x^2+4)(2x+8)-(x^2+8x-4)(4x^3)\over (x^2-4)^2(x^2+4)^2}$

The equation is $f(x)= {x\over x^2-4}-{x-1\over x^2+4}$

When I apply the quotient rule i get $f'(x)= {(1)(x^2-4)-(2x)(1)\over (x^2-4)^2}-{(1)(x^2+4)-(2x)(1)\over (x^2+4)^2}$ but it cancels each other out.  I can't figure out how they had gotten the answer.

Comment: I would use the quotient rule on each of the fractions first and then use lcd to combine them into a mega fraction :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a}{c} \neq \frac{a-a}{b}$$ but $$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a}{c}=\frac{ac-ab}{bc}$$

Notice that you have different denominators.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps me understand it a little more

Answer (score 0):

Most people screw up the Quotient Rule because they forget it. Quite actually, the quotient rule is just a corollary of the product rule (ie, the quotient rule is just a special case of the product rule)

The product rule states that that for two functions $u$ and $v_0$,

$$(uv_0)'= uv_0' + u'v_0$$

Let $$v_0 = \frac{1}{v} \implies v_0' =  -v'/v^2$$

So,
$$ \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' = u\cdot\frac{-v'}{v^2} + u'\cdot\frac{1}{v} = \frac{-uv'}{v^2} + \frac{u'v}{v^2} = \frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}$$
Hopefully, that was helpful.

Comment: I'm even more confused :/ but thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @CMLara: I'm so sorry, which part confuses you? I'll be more than happy to clarify.

Comment: don't be sorry. I just confuse on how to apply the quotient rule to this equation. I've tried numerous solutions but its not giving me the right answer. I'm very thankful tho.